# Adding custom actions to Craft Commerce orders page

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to add custom actions to the order page. Following the documentation on hooks and Element Actions, I did this

In my main plugin file (OrderExporterPlugin.php)

```
public function commerce_addOrderActions($source)
{
    return array(
        new OrderExporter_ExportElementAction()
    );
}
```

In the folder elementactions (OrderExporter_ExportElementAction.php)

```
class OrderExporter_ExportElementAction extends BaseElementAction {

   public function getName()
   {
    return Craft::t('Export file');
   }
```

}

The hook is active, but sends an error with the message "Class 'Craft\OrderExporter_ExportElementAction' not found" when trying to access that class

My IDE recognizes the class, so I think the namespaces are fine

Comment: Have you `require`'d the `OrderExporter_ExportElementAction` at some point in the request?  It won't get autoloaded for you.

Comment: Perhaps I’m just being an idiot but I think it would be useful to note in the docs that element actions need to be explicitly required, as most other plugin classes seem to autoload.